# How to ban lots of IP ranges?

Tags: php, .htaccess, block, detect, googlebot

How can I detect Google, not only crawlers, I mean in general.

According to [this site](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/traceipaddresses/f/google-ip-address.htm) the following IP address ranges belong to Google:

```
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.64.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255
```

(Are these really all of their IP addresses?)

Is there a simple way to ban all these hundreds of IPs from my website using PHP or .htaccess? I mean another way than:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if $ip == "64.233.160.0" || $ip = "64.233.160.1" ...) 
   //...
```

Comment: Are you trying to ban google? if so, why?, one answer below but you'd be better off doing this at a firewall level if you have it available and which doesn't impact your application in any way.

Comment: If it's just crawlers, you can set robots.txt no problem.

Comment: I don't trust Google, I don't like Google. I simply don't want it to be able to interact with my website in any way. It's really not a site that should be - or would benefit from being indexed anyway.  
Unfortunately I don't access to the firewall settings. PHP and .htaccess are my only options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PHP implementation which may be adaptable to load ranges from a database is shown below:

```
<?php

$ranges = [
    ['64.233.160.0', '64.233.191.255'],
    ['66.102.0.0'  , '66.102.15.255' ],
    ['66.249.64.0' , '66.249.95.255' ],
    ['72.14.192.0' , '72.14.255.255' ],
    ['74.125.0.0'  , '74.125.255.255'],
    ['209.85.128.0', '209.85.255.255'],
    ['216.239.32.0', '216.239.63.255']
];

function in_range($ip, $ranges) {
    $size = count($ranges);
    $longIP = ip2long($ip);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
        if ($longIP >= ip2long($ranges[$i][0]) && $longIP <= ip2long($ranges[$i][1]))
            return true;
    return false;
}

var_dump(in_range('64.233.160.168', $ranges));
var_dump(in_range('123.123.123.123', $ranges));
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/5701b7ce12ebf4):

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Comment: For now I'll go with that, until I looked deeper into the .htaccess method. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this by adding this to your .htacces file or your http.conf.

This is an example of how to block ranges. I used this on an old site.

```
# Get up-to-date list from http://www.okean.com/thegoods.html or (in .htaccess format) http://www.wizcrafts.net/chinese-blocklist.html
# China IP Address Blocks
deny from 58.14.0.0/15 58.16.0.0/13 58.24.0.0/15 58.30.0.0/15 58.32.0.0/11 58.66.0.0/15 58.68.128.0/17 58.82.0.0/15 58.87.64.0/18 58.99.128.0/17 58.100.0.0/15 58.116.0.0/14 58.128.0.0/13 58.144.0.0/16 58.154.0.0/15 58.192.0.0/11 58.240.0.0/12
deny from 59.32.0.0/11 59.64.0.0/13 59.72.0.0/15 59.77.0.0/16 59.78.0.0/15 59.80.0.0/14 59.107.0.0/16 59.108.0.0/14 59.151.0.0/17 59.155.0.0/16 59.172.0.0/14 59.191.0.0/16 59.192.0.0/10
deny from 60.0.0.0/11 60.55.0.0/16 60.63.0.0/16 60.160.0.0/11 60.194.0.0/15 60.200.0.0/13 60.208.0.0/12 60.232.0.0/15 60.235.0.0/16 60.245.128.0/17 60.247.0.0/16 60.252.0.0/16 60.253.128.0/17 60.255.0.0/16
deny from 61.4.80.0/20 61.4.176.0/20 61.8.160.0/20 61.28.0.0/17 61.29.128.0/17 61.45.128.0/18 61.47.128.0/18 61.48.0.0/13 61.87.192.0/18 61.128.0.0/10 61.232.0.0/14 61.236.0.0/15 61.240.0.0/14
deny from 116.1.0.0/16 116.2.0.0/15 116.4.0.0/14 116.8.0.0/14 116.13.0.0/16 116.16.0.0/12 116.52.0.0/14 116.56.0.0/15 116.58.128.0/20 116.58.208.0/20 116.60.0.0/14 116.66.0.0/17 116.69.0.0/16 116.70.0.0/17 116.76.0.0/14 116.89.144.0/20 116.90.184.0/21 116.95.0.0/16 116.112.0.0/14 116.116.0.0/15 116.128.0.0/10 116.192.0.0/16 116.193.16.0/20 116.193.32.0/19 116.194.0.0/15 116.196.0.0/16
deny from 116.198.0.0/16 116.199.0.0/17 116.199.128.0/19 116.204.0.0/15 116.207.0.0/16 116.208.0.0/14 116.212.160.0/20 116.213.64.0/18 116.213.128.0/17 116.214.32.0/19 116.214.64.0/20 116.214.128.0/17 116.215.0.0/16 116.216.0.0/14 116.224.0.0/12 116.242.0.0/15 116.244.0.0/14 116.248.0.0/15 116.252.0.0/15 116.254.128.0/17 116.255.128.0/17
deny from 117.8.0.0/13 117.21.0.0/16 117.22.0.0/15 117.24.0.0/13 117.32.0.0/13 117.40.0.0/14 117.44.0.0/15 117.48.0.0/14 117.53.176.0/20 117.57.0.0/16 117.58.0.0/17 117.59.0.0/16 117.60.0.0/14 117.64.0.0/13 117.72.0.0/15 117.74.64.0/20 117.74.128.0/17 117.75.0.0/16 117.76.0.0/14 117.80.0.0/12 117.100.0.0/15 117.103.16.0/20 117.103.128.0/20 117.106.0.0/15 117.112.0.0/13 117.120.64.0/18 117.120.128.0/17 117.121.0.0/17 117.121.128.0/18 117.121.192.0/21 117.122.128.0/17 117.124.0.0/14 117.128.0.0/10
deny from 118.24.0.0/13 118.64.0.0/15 118.66.0.0/16 118.67.112.0/20 118.72.0.0/13 118.80.0.0/15 118.84.0.0/15 118.88.32.0/19 118.88.64.0/18 118.88.128.0/17 118.89.0.0/16 118.91.240.0/20 118.102.16.0/20 118.112.0.0/13 118.120.0.0/14 118.124.0.0/15 118.126.0.0/16 118.132.0.0/14 118.144.0.0/14 118.178.0.0/16 118.180.0.0/14 118.184.0.0/13 118.192.0.0/12 118.212.0.0/15 118.224.0.0/14 118.228.0.0/15 118.230.0.0/16 118.239.0.0/16 118.242.0.0/16 118.244.0.0/14 118.248.0.0/13
deny from 119.0.0.0/15
deny from 121.0.16.0/20 121.4.0.0/15 121.8.0.0/13 121.16.0.0/12 121.32.0.0/13 121.40.0.0/14 121.46.0.0/15 121.48.0.0/15 121.51.0.0/16 121.52.160.0/19 121.52.208.0/20 121.52.224.0/19 121.55.0.0/18 121.56.0.0/15 121.58.0.0/17 121.58.144.0/20 121.59.0.0/16 121.60.0.0/14 121.68.0.0/14 121.76.0.0/15 121.79.128.0/18 121.89.0.0/16 121.100.128.0/17 121.192.0.0/13 121.201.0.0/16 121.204.0.0/14 121.224.0.0/12 121.248.0.0/14 121.255.0.0/16
deny from 122.0.64.0/18 122.0.128.0/17 122.4.0.0/14 122.8.0.0/13 122.48.0.0/16 122.49.0.0/18 122.51.0.0/16 122.64.0.0/11 122.96.0.0/15 122.102.0.0/20 122.102.64.0/19 122.112.0.0/14 122.119.0.0/16 122.136.0.0/13 122.144.128.0/17 122.156.0.0/14 122.192.0.0/14 122.198.0.0/16 122.200.64.0/18 122.204.0.0/14 122.224.0.0/12 122.240.0.0/13 122.248.48.0/20
deny from 123.0.128.0/18 123.4.0.0/14 123.8.0.0/13 123.49.128.0/17 123.52.0.0/14 123.56.0.0/13 123.64.0.0/11 123.96.0.0/15 123.98.0.0/17 123.99.128.0/17 123.100.0.0/19 123.101.0.0/16 123.103.0.0/17 123.108.128.0/20 123.108.208.0/20 123.112.0.0/12 123.128.0.0/13 123.136.80.0/20 123.137.0.0/16 123.138.0.0/15 123.144.0.0/12 123.160.0.0/12 123.176.80.0/20 123.177.0.0/16 123.178.0.0/15 123.180.0.0/14 123.184.0.0/13 123.196.0.0/15 123.199.128.0/17 123.232.0.0/14 123.244.0.0/14 123.249.0.0/16 123.253.0.0/16
deny from 124.6.64.0/18 124.14.0.0/15 124.16.0.0/15 124.20.0.0/14 124.28.192.0/18 124.29.0.0/17 124.31.0.0/16 124.40.112.0/20 124.40.128.0/18 124.42.0.0/16 124.47.0.0/18 124.64.0.0/15 124.66.0.0/17 124.67.0.0/16 124.68.0.0/14 124.72.0.0/13 124.88.0.0/13 124.108.8.0/21 124.108.40.0/21 124.112.0.0/13 124.126.0.0/15 124.128.0.0/13 124.147.128.0/17 124.156.0.0/16 124.160.0.0/13 124.172.0.0/14 124.192.0.0/15 124.196.0.0/16 124.200.0.0/13 124.220.0.0/14 124.224.0.0/12 124.240.0.0/17 124.242.0.0/16 124.243.192.0/18 124.248.0.0/17 124.249.0.0/16 124.250.0.0/15 124.254.0.0/18
deny from 125.31.192.0/18 125.32.0.0/12 125.58.128.0/17 125.61.128.0/17 125.62.0.0/18 125.64.0.0/11 125.96.0.0/15 125.98.0.0/16 125.104.0.0/13 125.112.0.0/12 125.169.0.0/16 125.171.0.0/16 125.208.0.0/18 125.210.0.0/15 125.213.0.0/17 125.214.96.0/19 125.215.0.0/18 125.216.0.0/13 125.254.128.0/17
deny from 134.196.0.0/16
deny from 159.226.0.0/16
deny from 161.207.0.0/16
deny from 162.105.0.0/16
deny from 166.111.0.0/16
deny from 167.139.0.0/16
deny from 168.160.0.0/16
deny from 192.83.122.0/24 192.124.154.0/24 192.188.170.0/24
deny from 198.17.7.0/24 198.97.132.0/24
deny from 202.0.110.0/24 202.0.160.0/20 202.0.176.0/22 202.4.128.0/19 202.4.252.0/22 202.8.128.0/19 202.10.64.0/20 202.14.88.0/24 202.14.235.0/24 202.14.236.0/23 202.14.238.0/24 202.20.120.0/24 202.22.248.0/21 202.38.0.0/20 202.38.64.0/18 202.38.128.0/21 202.38.136.0/23 202.38.138.0/24 202.38.140.0/22 202.38.144.0/22 202.38.149.0/24 202.38.150.0/23 202.38.152.0/22 202.38.156.0/24 202.38.158.0/23 202.38.160.0/23 202.38.164.0/22 202.38.168.0/21 202.38.176.0/23 202.38.184.0/21 202.38.192.0/18 202.41.152.0/21 202.41.240.0/20 202.46.32.0/19 202.46.224.0/20
deny from 202.60.112.0/20 202.69.4.0/22 202.69.16.0/20 202.70.0.0/19 202.74.8.0/21 202.75.208.0/20 202.85.208.0/20 202.90.0.0/22 202.90.224.0/20 202.90.252.0/22 202.91.0.0/22 202.91.128.0/22 202.91.176.0/20 202.91.224.0/19 202.92.0.0/22 202.92.252.0/22 202.93.0.0/22 202.93.252.0/22 202.94.0.0/19 202.95.0.0/19 202.95.252.0/22 202.96.0.0/12
deny from 202.112.0.0/13 202.120.0.0/15 202.122.0.0/19 202.122.32.0/21 202.122.64.0/19 202.122.112.0/21 202.122.128.0/24 202.123.96.0/20 202.124.24.0/21 202.125.176.0/20 202.127.0.0/18 202.127.112.0/20 202.127.128.0/19 202.127.160.0/21 202.127.192.0/18 202.130.0.0/19 202.130.224.0/19 202.131.16.0/21 202.131.48.0/20 202.131.208.0/20 202.136.48.0/20 202.136.208.0/20 202.136.224.0/20 202.141.160.0/19 202.142.16.0/20 202.143.16.0/20 202.148.96.0/19 202.149.160.0/20 202.149.224.0/19
deny from 202.150.16.0/20 202.152.176.0/20 202.153.48.0/20 202.158.160.0/19 202.160.176.0/20 202.164.0.0/20 202.164.25.0/24 202.165.96.0/21 202.165.176.0/20 202.165.208.0/20 202.168.160.0/19 202.170.128.0/19 202.170.216.0/21 202.173.8.0/21 202.173.224.0/19 202.179.240.0/20 202.180.128.0/19 202.181.112.0/20 202.189.80.0/20 202.192.0.0/12
deny from 203.18.50.0/24 203.79.0.0/20 203.80.144.0/20 203.81.16.0/20 203.83.56.0/21 203.86.0.0/18 203.86.64.0/19 203.88.0.0/22 203.88.32.0/19 203.88.192.0/19 203.89.0.0/22 203.90.0.0/22 203.90.128.0/18 203.90.192.0/19 203.91.32.0/19 203.91.96.0/20 203.91.120.0/21 203.92.0.0/22 203.92.160.0/19 203.93.0.0/16 203.94.0.0/18 203.95.0.0/21 203.95.96.0/19 203.99.16.0/20 203.99.80.0/20
deny from 203.100.32.0/20 203.100.80.0/20 203.100.96.0/19 203.100.192.0/20 203.110.160.0/19 203.118.192.0/19 203.119.24.0/21 203.119.32.0/22 203.128.32.0/19 203.128.96.0/19 203.128.128.0/19 203.130.32.0/19 203.132.32.0/19 203.134.240.0/21 203.135.96.0/19 203.135.160.0/20 203.148.0.0/18 203.152.64.0/19 203.156.192.0/18 203.158.16.0/21 203.161.192.0/19 203.166.160.0/19 203.171.224.0/20 203.174.7.0/24 203.174.96.0/19 203.175.128.0/19 203.175.192.0/18 203.176.168.0/21 203.184.80.0/20 203.187.160.0/19 203.190.96.0/20 203.191.16.0/20 203.191.64.0/18 203.191.144.0/20 203.192.0.0/19 203.196.0.0/22
deny from 203.207.64.0/18 203.207.128.0/17 203.208.0.0/20 203.208.16.0/22 203.208.32.0/19 203.209.224.0/19 203.212.0.0/20 203.212.80.0/20 203.222.192.0/20 203.223.0.0/20
deny from 210.2.0.0/19 210.5.0.0/19 210.5.32.0/20 210.5.144.0/20 210.12.0.0/15 210.14.64.0/19 210.14.112.0/20 210.14.128.0/17 210.15.0.0/17 210.15.128.0/18 210.16.128.0/18 210.21.0.0/16 210.22.0.0/16 210.23.32.0/19 210.25.0.0/16 210.26.0.0/15 210.28.0.0/14 210.32.0.0/12 210.51.0.0/16 210.52.0.0/15 210.56.192.0/19 210.72.0.0/14 210.76.0.0/15 210.78.0.0/16 210.79.64.0/18 210.79.224.0/19 210.82.0.0/15 210.87.128.0/18 210.185.192.0/18 210.192.96.0/19
deny from 211.64.0.0/13 211.80.0.0/12 211.96.0.0/13 211.136.0.0/13 211.144.0.0/12 211.160.0.0/13
deny from 218.0.0.0/11 218.56.0.0/13 218.64.0.0/11 218.96.0.0/14 218.104.0.0/14 218.108.0.0/15 218.192.0.0/12 218.240.0.0/13 218.249.0.0/16
deny from 219.72.0.0/16 219.82.0.0/16 219.128.0.0/11 219.216.0.0/13 219.224.0.0/12 219.242.0.0/15 219.244.0.0/14
deny from 220.101.192.0/18 220.112.0.0/14 220.152.128.0/17 220.154.0.0/15 220.160.0.0/11 220.192.0.0/12 220.231.0.0/18 220.231.128.0/17 220.232.64.0/18 220.234.0.0/16 220.242.0.0/15 220.248.0.0/14
deny from 221.0.0.0/13 221.8.0.0/14 221.12.0.0/17 221.12.128.0/18 221.13.0.0/16 221.14.0.0/15 221.122.0.0/15 221.129.0.0/16 221.130.0.0/15 221.133.224.0/19 221.136.0.0/15 221.172.0.0/14 221.176.0.0/13 221.192.0.0/14 221.196.0.0/15 221.198.0.0/16 221.199.0.0/17 221.199.128.0/18 221.199.192.0/20 221.199.224.0/19 221.200.0.0/13 221.208.0.0/12 221.224.0.0/12
deny from 222.16.0.0/12 222.32.0.0/11 222.64.0.0/11 222.125.0.0/16 222.126.128.0/17 222.128.0.0/12 222.160.0.0/14 222.168.0.0/13 222.176.0.0/12 222.192.0.0/11 222.240.0.0/13 222.248.0.0/16 222.249.0.0/17 222.249.128.0/18 222.249.192.0/19 222.249.224.0/20 222.249.240.0/21 222.249.248.0/23
# Korea IP addresses follow:
deny from 58.72.0.0/13 58.239.0.0/16 58.140.0.0/14 59.0.0.0/11 59.186.0.0/15 61.248.0.0/13 121.128.0.0/10 122.99.128.0/17 124.50.87.161 125.128.0.0/11 125.176.0.0/12 143.248.0.0/16 211.41.224.0/19 211.104.0.0/13 211.112.0.0/13 211.211.36.0/23 218.144.138.0/26 219.240.0.0/15 219.248.0.0/13 221.128.0.0/12 221.144.0.0/12 221.160.0.0/13 221.168.0.0/16 221.163.46.0/24
# Malaysia
deny from 60.48.0.0/13 202.71.102.0/24 203.223.128.0/19
# Thailand
deny from 58.137.13.0/24 203.113.13.0/24 203.144.144.0/24 203.149.0.0/18 203.155.0.0/16
# Vietnam
deny from 58.187.112.0/20 125.234.0.0/15 203.113.128.0/18
# Nigeria IP Address Blocks
deny from 12.166.96.32/27 41.202.0.0/17 41.202.128.0/19 41.204.0.0/17 41.204.128.0/18 41.204.224.0/19 41.205.160.0/19 41.207.0.0/19 41.207.192.0/19 41.208.128.0/18 41.210.0.0/18 41.211.192.0/18 41.219.192.0/18 41.220.0.0/16 41.222.24.0/21 41.222.40.0/21 41.222.64.0/21 41.223.24.0/22 41.223.248.0/22 41.248.0.0/16 41.250.0.0/16 61.11.230.112/29 62.56.128.0/17 62.56.235.0/24 62.56.236.0/24 62.56.244.0/22 62.56.248.0/24 62.128.160.0/20 62.173.32.0/19 62.192.128.0/19 62.192.140.250 62.193.160.0/19
deny from 63.70.178.0/24 63.73.58.0/24 63.100.193.0/24 63.103.138.0/24 63.103.139.64/26 63.103.140.0/22 63.109.245.168/29 63.109.248.128/25 63.122.154.0/24 64.14.48.128/26 62.24.96.0/19 64.86.155.0/24 64.86.210.0/23 64.110.30.0/24 64.110.31.0/24 64.110.64.16/28 64.110.76.0/23 64.110.81.0/24 64.110.93.16/28 64.110.93.176/28 64.110.147.0/24 64.201.33.0/24 65.209.91.0/24 65.209.92.0/24 66.18.64.0/19 66.110.31.0/24 66.178.0.0/17 66.199.241.82 66.205.20.0/24 77.220.0.0/20
deny from 80.78.16.168/29 80.78.16.176/28 80.78.16.192/28 80.78.17.0/24 80.78.18.88/29 80.78.18.96/27 80.78.18.128/29 80.87.64.0/19 80.88.128.0/20 80.88.129.0/24 80.88.130.0/24 80.88.131.0/24 80.88.132.0/26 80.88.132.64/27 80.88.132.104/29 80.88.132.128/26 80.88.132.192/27 80.88.132.224/28 80.88.132.240/29 80.88.133.0/25 80.88.134.0/26 80.88.134.64/29 80.88.135.0/24 80.88.136.0/24 80.88.137.0/24 80.88.138.0/25 80.88.138.128/26 80.88.138.192/27 80.88.139.0/25 80.88.139.128/26 80.88.139.192/27 80.88.139.224/28
deny from 80.88.140.0/24 80.88.141.0/25 80.88.141.128/27 80.88.142.0/24 80.88.143.128/24 80.88.144.0/23 80.88.146.0/24 80.88.147.0/24 80.88.148.0/24 80.88.149.0/25 80.88.149.128/26 80.88.149.192/28 80.88.150.0/24 80.88.151.0/24 80.88.152.0/24 80.88.153.0/24 80.88.154.32/27 80.88.154.72/29 80.88.154.80/29 80.88.154.96/28 80.88.155.0/25 80.88.155.128/27 80.88.155.160/29 80.89.176.0/24
deny from 80.179.102.0/24 80.179.107.64/27 80.179.107.224/29 80.179.128.0/17 80.231.4.0/23 80.240.192.0/20 80.247.136.0/24 80.247.137.0/24 80.247.141.32/27 80.247.141.64/26 80.247.141.128/25 80.247.142.0/24 80.247.147.16/28 80.247.147.32/29 80.247.147.64/27 80.247.147.96/28 80.247.151.0/24 80.247.153.0/24 80.247.156.0/26 80.247.156.128/28 80.247.157.0/24 80.247.159.0/24 80.248.0.0/20 80.248.64.0/23 80.248.70.0/20 80.248.64.0/20 80.250.32.0/20
deny from 80.255.40.48/28 80.255.40.96/29 80.255.40.112/28 80.255.40.128/28 80.255.40.192/28 80.255.40.224/27 80.255.40.240/28 80.255.43.0/24 80.255.46.0/29 80.255.46.16/28 80.255.46.64/29 80.255.58.160/27 80.255.58.192/26 80.255.59.19 80.255.59.0/24
deny from 81.18.32.0/20 81.18.40.0/24 81.18.42.0/24 81.23.194.0/27 81.23.194.64/27 81.23.194.128/25 81.23.195.0/24 81.23.196.0/25 81.23.196.128/29 81.23.200.0/21 81.24.0.0/20 81.91.224.0/20 81.199.0.0/16 81.199.6.0/24 81.199.7.0/24 81.199.48.0/20 81.199.72.0/22 81.199.76.0/24 81.199.82.0/23 81.199.84.0/22 81.199.84.0/24 81.199.85.0/24 81.199.86.0/24 81.199.87.0/24 81.199.88.0/24 81.199.89.0/24 81.199.90.0/24 81.199.94.0/23 81.199.108.0/22 81.199.124.0/22 81.199.172.160/27 81.199.240.0/21 82.128.0.0/17 82.205.242.0/23
deny from 83.137.61.0/24 83.138.167.40/29 83.229.0.0/17 84.254.188.3 84.254.128.0/18 155.239.0.0/16 192.116.64.0/18 192.116.128.0/18 192.116.152.0/21 193.110.2.0/23 193.189.0.0/18 193.189.64.0/23 193.189.128.0/24 193.194.64.0/19 193.219.192.0/18 193.220.0.0/16 193.220.26.0/24 193.220.30.0/26 193.220.30.64/27 193.220.31.0/26 193.220.31.64/27 193.220.45.0/25 193.220.47.0/25 193.220.77.0/26 193.220.187.0/26 193.220.187.128/27
deny from 195.8.22.0/24 195.24.192.0/19 195.44.168.0/21 195.44.176.0/21 195.137.13.0/24 195.137.14.0/24 195.166.224.0/19 195.219.176.0/24 195.225.62.0/23 195.245.108.0/23 196.0.0.0/9 196.128.0.0/10 196.192.0.0/12 196.220.0.0/19 198.54.0.0/16
deny from 204.118.170.0/24 208.70.0.0/21 208.78.56.0/21 209.88.163.0/24 209.101.84.0/24 209.159.160.0/20 209.198.240.0/23 209.198.242.16/28 209.198.242.96/29 209.198.242.104/30 209.198.242.108/31 209.198.242.128/27 209.198.246.240/28 212.49.64.0/19 212.60.64.0/19 212.85.192.0/19 212.96.0.0/19 212.100.64.0/19 212.165.128.0/17 212.165.132.64/27 212.165.135.0/24 212.165.140.16/29 212.165.140.64/26 212.165.140.128/25 212.165.141.0/24 212.165.147.0/26 212.165.147.128/26 212.165.183.0/24 212.199.108.0/24 212.199.251.0/24 212.247.93.0/24
deny from 213.136.96.0/19 213.140.62.0/23 213.150.192.0/23 213.154.64.0/19 213.166.160.0/19 213.181.64.0/19 213.185.96.0/21 213.185.106.0/24 213.185.112.0/24 213.185.113.0/26 213.185.113.64/27 213.185.113.96/27 213.185.118.192/26 213.185.124.0/24 213.187.135.0/24 213.187.145.0/24 213.211.128.0/18 213.211.188.0/24 213.232.96.0/24 213.255.193.0/24 213.255.194.0/24 213.255.195.0/24 213.255.198.0/24 213.255.199.0/24
deny from 216.72.104.0/21 216.74.187.0/24 216.118.252.0/24 216.118.253.0/24 216.129.147.128/28 216.129.159.0/24 216.133.174.0/24 216.139.160.0/19 216.139.176.136/29 216.147.132.144/28 216.147.132.160/28 216.147.134.0/24 216.147.159.0/24 216.185.79.0/24 216.236.200.96/28 216.236.202.96/28 216.236.205.0/24 216.236.222.128/26 216.250.195.0/27 216.250.195.64/26 216.250.221.0/24 216.250.222.0/24 216.252.176.0/24 216.252.177.0/24 216.252.231.0/25 216.252.245.0/24
deny from 217.10.163.128/26 217.10.163.192/27 217.10.163.224/27 217.10.166.0/26 217.10.166.64/28 217.10.169.0/24 217.10.170.0/24 217.10.171.0/24 217.10.173.0/26 217.10.182.0/27 217.10.184.0/24 217.14.80.0/20 217.15.124.0/25 217.20.240.0/20 217.20.241.0/25 217.20.241.128/29 217.20.241.136/29 217.20.241.144/28 217.20.241.160/29 217.20.241.168/29 217.20.241.176/29 217.20.241.184/29 217.20.241.192/29 217.20.241.200/29 217.20.241.208/29 217.20.242.0/24 217.20.243.16/28 217.20.243.32/27 217.78.64.0/20
deny from 217.117.0.0/20 217.146.3.144/28 217.146.3.160/28 217.146.3.176/29 217.146.3.224/27 217.146.4.64/26 217.146.5.0/24 217.146.6.0/25 217.146.6.160/27 217.146.7.0/24 217.146.8.0/25 217.146.9.0/24 217.146.10.128/25 217.146.11.0/25 217.146.12.0/24 217.146.13.0/24 217.146.14.0/25 217.146.15.0/25 217.146.16.0/27 217.146.16.32/29 217.168.112.0/20 217.194.140.0/22 217.194.144.0/20 217.199.144.0/20 217.212.242.0/23
# Russia and Ukraine and Bulgaria and Romania and Latvia and Estonia
deny from 77.120.0.0/14
deny from 78.106.0.0/15
deny from 79.120.0.0/17
deny from 80.73.64.0/21 80.85.176.0/20
deny from 81.19.64.0/19 81.95.144.0/20 81.176.0.0/15
deny from 82.76.0.0/14 82.103.64.0/18 82.138.6.128/25 82.144.192.0/19 82.151.112.0/21 82.160.203.0/24
deny from 83.219.129.0/24 83.237.0.0/16
deny from 85.14.35.0/24 85.112.112.0/20 85.140.0.0/15 85.142.0.0/15 85.192.60.0/23 85.249.128.0/19 85.255.112.0/20
deny from 86.127.19.0/24
deny from 87.99.64.0/19 87.103.192.0/20 87.120.16.0/20 87.242.116.0/23
deny from 89.122.0.0/16 89.37.144.0/21 89.111.176.0/20 89.175.0.0/16 89.178.0.0/15 89.190.224.0/19
deny from 91.76.0.0/14 91.124.0.0/16
deny from 141.85.0.0/16
deny from 192.129.3.0/24
deny from 193.39.113.0/24 193.47.166.0/24 193.178.144.0/22
deny from 194.44.36.0/24 194.186.0.0/16
deny from 195.28.32.0/19 195.34.224.0/19 195.95.218.0/23 195.5.116.0/23 195.137.200.0/23 195.138.198.0/24 195.189.246.0/23 195.208.0.0/15 195.225.176.0/22 195.239.0.0/16 195.242.98.0/23 195.244.128.128/25 195.245.112.0/23
deny from 212.24.32.0/19 212.58.192.0/19 212.158.160.0/20
deny from 213.91.128.0/17 213.140.96.0/19 213.154.192.0/19 213.242.12.0/22 213.248.48.0/20
deny from 217.12.240.0/20 217.16.16.0/20 217.77.208.0/20 217.174.96.0/20
```

Comment: How exactly doe it work? What ranges are blocked in that file? Is there a documentation on this "command".

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html

Answer (score 0):

For to detect Google Bot they suggest to do reverse DNS resolution

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en

You can do reverse DNS in PHP with `gethostbyaddr`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php